# how to fix images causing "karma WARN [web-server]: 404"?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an angular directive with a template that is doing something like:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" />
```

In my test, I am setting the scope so that url points to a fictitious image...  Karma then says:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /fake.png
```

So I go into my karma config file and add to the files array:

```
{pattern: 'spec/javascripts/fixtures/**/*.png', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
```

And then added proxies:

```
proxies: {
  '/fake.png': 'spec/javascripts/fixtures/assets/fake.png'
}
```

...

Now I get:

```
WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy spec/javascripts/fixtures/assets/fake.png ([object Object])
```

?

That path is correct, and there is a real image called fake.png there.

The basePath in my config is also properly set to the root of my project...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out through random trial and error.  Apparently you have to use the **magic** word "base" in your path.

```
proxies: {
  '/fake.png': '/base/spec/javascripts/fixtures/assets/fake.png'
}
```

now it works, but let's be honest, prepending **"/base"** just seems like nonsense.

Comment: Wow, I hunted that **base** keyword for hours. Make it bolder.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about showing the actual image in the tests this is enough:

```
proxies: {
  '/fake.png': ''
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer here

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to comment, but I don't have enough rep, as I am a SO newbie. `/base` is the base path from the karma config. You specify that in

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        ...
        basePath: '../',
        ...
    }    
}
```

When you do that, the base part is automatically prepended to the pattern. So there is not really nonsense going on, but incomplete configuration.
Have a great one :)

Comment: I not really sure.. I think `basePath` is just where to find the files but still they are served at `/base/whatever-path-relative-to-base-path`